# Merge Object AngularJS from two http request

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, merge

I'm trying to merge two HTTP.get request into one `$scope` because i want to display the data in same `ng-repeat` table. Im using chained promises like this in my AngularJS application:

**AngularJS:**

```
function getContainer() {
            $http.get("/api/containers")
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.GTMcontainersAccount = response.data;
                    $scope.loading = false;


                    // Retrive containerId and AccountID then request to show Counter of how many Tags, Triggers and Variables are available in each Container
                    angular.forEach($scope.GTMcontainersAccount, function (key) {
                        angular.forEach(key, function (keydata) {
                            $scope.accountId = keydata.accountId;
                            $scope.containerId = keydata.containerId;
                            $http.get("/api/tags", {
                                params: {
                                    "param1": $scope.accountId,
                                    "param2": $scope.containerId
                                }
                            }).then(function (responses) {
                                $scope.tags_counter = responses.data[""]['tags'];
                                $scope.trigger_counter = responses.data[""]['trigger'];
                                $scope.variable_counter = responses.data[""]['variable'];


                            })
                        })

                    })
                })
        }
```

Explain what i do in the code:
1) `http.get(/api/containers)` gives me some data in JSON-format
2) angular.forEach iterates trough the keys
3) angular.forEach iterates trough the value (key are dynamic thats why there are 2 angular.forEach.
4) `http.get(/api/tags)` i send some data in parameter and get some result data

5) Here is the difficult part, i want to use ng-repeat on `$scope.GTMcontainersAccount` but cannot merge `$scope.GTMcontainersAccount` with `$scope.tags_counter`, `$scope.trigger_counter` and `$scope.variable_counter`

My data in `$scope.GTMcontainersAccount`:

```
{
    "Account2": [{
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7454209",
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7519183",
    }],
    "Account 1": [{
        "accountId": "1766143525",
        "containerId": "7483653",
    }]
}
```

My data in `$scope.tags_counter:` (ive deleted alot because its very long and whats important here is the LAST key:value)

```
{
    "0": {
        "accountId": "****",
        "containerId": "*****",
        "tag": [{
            "accountId": "*****",
            "containerId": "********",
            "name": "Test Tag"
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Classic Google Analytics"
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "contentEngagement"
        }],
        "trigger": [{
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Trigger 1"
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Trigger 2"
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Trigger 3"
        }],
        "variable": [{
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Google Analytics Settings"
        }, {
            "name": "Protocol"
        }, {
            "accountId": "*******",
            "containerId": "****",
            "name": "Lookup Table"
        }],
        "builtInVariable": [{
            "accountId": "*******",
            "containerId": "******",
            "name": "Page URL",
            "path": null,
            "type": "pageUrl",
            "workspaceId": null
        }, {
            "accountId": "**",
            "containerId": "**",
            "name": "Page Hostname",
            "path": null,
            "type": "pageHostname",
            "workspaceId": null
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Page Path",
            "path": null,
            "type": "pagePath",
            "workspaceId": null
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "***",
            "name": "Referrer",
            "path": null,
            "type": "referrer",
            "workspaceId": null
        }, {
            "accountId": "***",
            "containerId": "****",
            "name": "Event",
            "path": null,
            "type": "event",
            "workspaceId": null
        }]
    },
    "": {                 <----- THIS is what i want to merge
        "tags": 3,
        "trigger": 3,
        "variable": 3
    }
}
```

So after the merge i want `$scope.GTMcontainersAccount` to look like this:
**Final:**

```
{
    "Account2": [{
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7454209",
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7519183",
    }],
    "Account 1": [{
        "accountId": "1766143525",
        "containerId": "7483653",
    }],
    "Counter" : {
        "tags": 3,
        "trigger": 3,
        "variable": 3
}
```

UPDATED:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've brought a fiddle for you.

It seems like a little messy but this works well.

I hope this is helpful for you. :)

[Merge Object](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/3s2xzsLz/1/)

```
$scope.GTMcontainersAccount['Counter'] = Object.values($scope.tags_counter)[(Object.keys($scope.tags_counter).length-1)];
```

Adding some explanations,

```
(Object.keys($scope.tags_counter).length-1)
```

Above is for getting last index of an object.

`Object.keys($scope.tags_counter)` returns all `keys` of `$scope.tags_counter`.

And `Object.values($scope.tags_counter)[ index ]` returns all `values` of `$scope.tags_counter`,

so when you know the index of value that you want, it's easy to get value of any object.

**UPDATE**

I'm confused because of your picture.

Why all lines have the same 'Counter' object.

It's doubtful whether you are putting the same object from '$scope.tags_counter' into different objects or not.

If the key what you want to get is always empty string like `""`,

then you can use `$scope.tags_counter[""];`.

Check [this other fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/3s2xzsLz/3/) please.

Or could you make fiddle which has your entire objects?

.

.

**UPDATE2**

Following more certain of your purpose, I've made this fiddle again.

[Please check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/3s2xzsLz/4/),

and if this is not right for your intent too, then please share me another information.

Comment: console.log($scope.GTMcontainersAccount); says undefined

Comment: @Asim In my fiddle?? I've checked again and it works well!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please see this and give me another feedback.

Comment: Uve misunderstood. The "Counter" should be inside each block of example "account2" or "Account1". this is just appending it to the last.

Comment: @Asim What you want is put same 'Counter' object into 'account1' and 'account2'?